# emmet selecting custom classes in css

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, emmet

I wanna select my custom classes of HTML in CSS file through emmet like `className="my_class"`.
Is there any way that emmet suggests the custom classes of HTML in CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for support autocomplete for custom CSS classes, you have to build a **VS code extension**, for that read [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api).

If you frequently use **same set of custom CSS class names** in your projects, you can define [custom emmet snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets) for quick auto completion.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. 
Is there any way Emmet suggests the custom classes in VS Code?

Comment: @AnjumAyoub updated the answer. term you need is not suggestions, but auto completion. Please accept the answer if answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this extension:  [className completion in css](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zitup.classnametocss).

[image: using classNames in css]

> Supported File Extensions
>
> HTML/HTM
>
> JSX/TSX
>    Vue
>   CSS
>     Less
>   Sass
>   Stylus

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I want 